# Angular: How do you identify JSON objects with id's?

Tags: arrays, json, angular, object

To hopefully simplify my question, I have broken it down like so:

#### What I do understand

If this is my object:

```
{ 
     things: [{
         'text': 'version'
         'short': 'v',
         'order': 1,
         'id': 'A'
     },{
         'text': 'update'
         'short': 'u',
         'order': 2,
         'id': 'B'
     }]
}
```

...then this is my type class:

```
 export class Thing {
     text: string;
     short: string;
     order: number;
     id: string;
 }
```

#### What I do not understand

If *this* is my data:

```
 { things: {
         'A': {
             'text': 'version'
             'short': 'v',
             'order': 1,
             'id': 'A'
         },
         'B': {
             'text': 'update'
             'short': 'u'
             'order': 2
             'id': 'B'
         }
     }
 }
```

...then the type class is...?

I have tried some really creative, ineffective tries to get this to work to no avail. I'm also hoping I can make sense of what to do with this non-array array (no square-brackets). Apologies if this is a duplicate.

Comment: JSON is a *textual notation* for data exchange. [(More here.)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2904181/157247) If you're dealing with JavaScript source code, and not dealing with a *string*, you're not dealing with JSON.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In that second situation, your `things` type would be an [*index type*](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#index-types-and-string-index-signatures) like this:

```
interface ThingHolder {
    [key: string]: Thing;
}
```

That says that the keys are strings and the values are `Thing`s.

The interface for `data` would be something that has a `things` property of that type:

```
interface AppropriateNameHere {
  things: ThingHolder;
}
```

So then, the compiler is happy with this:

```
const data : AppropriateNameHere = {
  things: {
    'A': {
      'text': 'version',
      'short': 'v',
      'order': 1,
      'id': 'A'
    },
    'B': {
      'text': 'update',
      'short': 'u',
      'order': 2,
      'id': 'B'
    }
  }
};
```

[Live Example](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=export%20class%20Thing%20%7B%0A%20%20text%3A%20string%3B%0A%20%20short%3A%20string%3B%0A%20%20order%3A%20number%3B%0A%20%20id%3A%20string%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Ainterface%20ThingHolder%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%5Bkey%3A%20string%5D%3A%20Thing%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Ainterface%20AppropriateNameHere%20%7B%0A%20%20things%3A%20ThingHolder%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aconst%20data%20%3A%20AppropriateNameHere%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20things%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20'A'%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20'text'%3A%20'version'%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20'short'%3A%20'v'%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20'order'%3A%201%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20'id'%3A%20'A'%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20'B'%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20'text'%3A%20'update'%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20'short'%3A%20'u'%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20'order'%3A%202%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20'id'%3A%20'B'%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%3B) on the TypeScript playground.

Comment: Excellent! Thanks very much!